# Is there a way to override a css, js, or image route call through javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, zip

I'm working on a way to take a .zip archive that has an .html file in it and be able to view it within an iframe. I have been able to unzip the archive and have access to all files within the archive using jszip. I am then putting the .html file as the source for an iframe.

The problem I am having is I am getting a 404 for the calls it is doing to find the files. Since at this time they are stored in memory and not actually able to be called through a route. I'm wondering if there is a way to detect when it's calling that route through javascript, because if I can create a function to detect that the route is being called, maybe I can push it the file it is looking for. Unless someone thinks there is a better way to do this.

Comment: We are trying to save time by making the zipped html file viewable in the browser. The html loads, but when it tries to find the css, js, and image files it tries to find these files in a place that doesn't exist.

Comment: I understand now. AFAIK it's not possible to do that the way you want. I think you could instead just replace all paths in that HTML file to data URIs.